# Powershell UseDefaultCredentials isn't working in remote session

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run the Invoke-WebRequest command on a remote machine.
The account I'm using is a local administrator on both machines.
If I log into a remote machine and run 
`Invoke-WebRequest $url -UseDefaultCredentials`, it works perfectly.

However, when I run 
`Invoke-Command -ComputerName machineName -ScriptBlock { Invoke-WebRequest "the path" -UseDefaultCredentials }` on my local machine, it gives me 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
I've also tried starting a remote session; 
`Enter-PSSession -ComputerName machineName` and then just running `Invoke-WebRequest "the path" -UseDefaultCredentials`, but this has the same result.

Why is this the case? What has changed about the permissions when running remotely? How can I work around it without being prompted for a password and without storing the password in a script?

Comment: This could be a second hop issue.  Try using -Auth CredSSP on Invoke-Command.

Comment: Thanks, but that still requires the credentials to be provided. It looks like I won't be able to avoid that though.

Answer (score 1):

On the remote servers run the following: `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server –Force`

(it seems you have to do this manually; the following does not work:

```
$remoteHosts | %{
    invoke-command -ComputerName $_ -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
        Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server –Force | out-null
    }
}
```

Then use the following code to enable the local machine to trust the remote one, then call it making use of this trust.
NB: commented out code's for if you wished to call a remote machine in a different domain.

```
[string[]]$remoteHosts = @('server1','server2')

$remoteHosts | %{Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer $_ -Force} | out-null

#if dealing with remote domains
#$trustedBefore = (Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts).value
#winrm set winrm/config/client ("@{{TrustedHosts='{0}'}}" -f (($remoteHosts + $remoteHosts) -join ',')) | out-null
$cred = get-credential
$remoteHosts | %{
    InvokeCommand -ScriptBlock {
        invoke-webrequest 'https://myUrl/' -UseDefaultCredentials | select StatusCode 
    } -Computer $_ -Credential $cred -Authentication Credssp
}
#winrm set winrm/config/client ("@{{TrustedHosts='{0}'}}" -f $trustedBefore) | out-null
```

Ref: Second Hop Security Issue
    http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx

Ref: Remote Computer in Different Domain
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx

NB: you may also find the remote servers are on a different PS version (i.e. older OSes have PS2 by default).
If you get that, below's a rough approximation of `Invoke-WebRequest` for PS2 (needs to be included in the script block)

```
function Invoke-PS2WebRequest {
    param(
        $Uri
    )
    try {
        $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($Uri)
        $request.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
        $request.PreAuthenticate = $true
        $resp = $request.GetResponse()
        $reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream()
        $sr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream
        $result = $sr.ReadToEnd()
        write-output (new-object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ 
            StatusDescription = $resp.StatusDescription
            StatusCode = [int]$resp.StatusCode
            Content = $result
        })
    } catch {
        write-output (new-object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ 
            StatusDescription = 'ERROR'
            StatusCode = [int]([regex]::matches($_.exception.message, "(?<=\()[\d]{3}").Value)
            Content = $_.exception.message
        })        
    }
}
```